# how to get the value of an array that does not exist, if there is no need to be taken php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm newbie in arrays. My code is:

```
$array = array(
         8 => array(14 => 10, 13 => 9, 12 => 7, 5 => 7, 15 => 8), 
         11 => array(25 => 8, 24 => 8)
); 

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
   print_r($value);
}
```

The output is:

```
10,9,7,7,8,8,8
```

The output I want:

```
10,9,7,8
```

Is it possible?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use array_unique() function to get the distinct values inside an array

http://php.net/array_unique